# How to redirect www.example.com to example.com?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

My MVC4 app is hosted on Azure (shared website) and works fine at exaple.com.
I'd like to redirect www.example.com to example.com, but it reports 404 error if accessed at www.example.com.

What should I add and is it the proper way to solve this problem?
I don't think it's DNS problem as I have asked it on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/470888/azure-hosted-website-gives-404-error-when-domain-name-is-preceded-by-www).

I have tried to redirect via Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="WWW Rewrite" stopProcessing="true" enabled="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www[.](.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't Azure let you specify multiple domains and a canonical?

Comment: @GrantThomas: it does, but in that case I will have two URLs pointing to the same website, which is not good for Google ranking and analytics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have a DNS record for both: www.mysite.com and mysite.com, either A or CNAME. Then, on the web server you should setup a "301" redirect that would redirect all requests from www.mysite.com to mysite.com.

If you don't mind people using both, then just a CNAME record in your DNS zone should do the trick:

```
www IN CNAME mysite.com
```

I think there is a way to register with Google and tell it to always use one or the other to index your site.

Comment: setting up 301 redirect on Azure website is the problem I'm having now.

Comment: I tried your example with web.config above on my IIS (I don't have Azure account) and it worked as you want: basically strips "www." from the URL. What kind of error/behaviour are you getting? Do you have your DNS setup so www.mysite.com points to site.com?

Comment: yes, I have CNAME for www that points to @ (otherwise I'd get Server Not Found error). In my case I get Server Error 404 - File or directory not found.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the rewrite section in Web.config *both* domain names (example.com and www.example.com) have to be configured in Azure as custom domains.
Then everything works as desired.